# Do employers allow workers to review materials relevant for the job during the working hours?

Tags: employer-relations, employer, review

I am a fresh college graduate. I was wondering the following: **Do employers allow employees to review materials relevant for the job during the working hours?**

For example, let's say I am working as a machine learning engineer. Let's say that for a particular job task I have to review the math relevant to machine learning. Could I take a book that covers the math topics relevant to machine learning and work through the book during my regular work hours?

Comment: You will have to ask your boss as this will vary from place to place, gotta VTC for that reason I fear.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul what does VTC mean?

Comment: Vote to close, as this makes the question off topic here. There is no universal blanket rules around the issue you are describing, it will all vary from company to company, so we cannot really answer this. Check out the [tour]

Comment: @JoeStrazzere let's say it takes me 2 weeks of full-time work to thoroughly review the material. I could glance at the parts I need a refresher at and that'd take about 15-30 minutes.

Comment: @Eternal_Ether - Re your last comment, *let's say it takes me 2 weeks of full-time work to thoroughly review the material.* That would be a sharp "no" from all but the most forward looking of employers, and only if you have proven that you deserve it. After hours local professional society meetings hould be on your own time. Learning a new subject by reading books you bought should be on your own time. As a nerdy professional (and "machine learning engineer" places you deep in the ranks of "nerdy professional"), you are expected to do some things on your own time to keep yourself current.

Comment: I can't imagine any professional setting where the rules are so draconian that one would need to ask for permission, let alone ever be denied, access to reference materials. NO ONE can keep everything in their head. Perhaps in some "air-gapped" high security workplaces web access would be out of the question, but physical paper books? Who would have such a rule?

Comment: @DavidHammen, it appears the OP is talking about an occasional 15-30 minute reading from a book.

Comment: @teego - Read the OP's comment from 57 minutes ago. It's the comment right above my comment.

Comment: @teego1967 - Taking a 15 minute break or two a day to read a part of a book is fine. People are allowed breaks, even in the most draconian "air gapped high seciurity" settings (your words). But that would require over a year to get through a book. That is not the way to get through a book on a highly technical subject.

Comment: Generally reference materials are not only allowed but encouraged. Unsure why this question is closed. I've never worked anywhere where it was disallowed. Joes answer pretty much covers it, but vtro anyway.

Comment: This question is confusing, because it says, "I am working as a machine learning engineer", but then posits the need to read an entire book on how to be a machine learning engineer. Is the book a basic text, or some advanced work? Is it specialized to the project at hand? Is it something learned earlier, and now in need of review?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Do employers allow employees to review materials relevant for the job
> during the working hours?

Many do. Some don't.

It depends on the job, your role, the employer's expectations, etc.

For some jobs, you are expected to know how to do the work without consulting materials. For other jobs, reviewing such materials are a normal part of the process.

> Could I take a book that covers the math topics relevant to machine
> learning and work through the book during my regular work hours?

Using such a book as a reference probably makes sense. Trying to learn how to do your job from such a book probably doesn't.

When in doubt, discuss it with your boss.

Comment: Totally depends. OTOH reading such a book when moving to an new framework or getting in as a junior developer where the employer KNOWS that you lack this type of knowledge is also quite normal. I have had contracts where I spent MONTHS getting into the codebase and reading up on references.

Answer (score 0):

> Do employers allow employees to review materials relevant for the job during the working hours?

Strictly answering the question, some do, some do not.

I'm going to infer there's an XY problem at hand here: "How much time should be spent on self-learning?" which again depends on your manager/employer, but if they are a competent manager of a tech company, they should expect a certain amount to be allocated to pure research, depending on the exact job role.

You specifically mention "machine learning engineer". This could be:

- Software engineer - you are taking pieces developed by other software engineers and data engineers and putting them into an application
- Data engineer - taking researched algorithms and putting them into a pipeline for use in production
- Data scientist / analyst - you have reams of data you need to make sense of
- Researcher - researching and developing novel algorithms
- Senior engineer - like the above, but you also have some engineers/scientists
- PI (primary investigator) - you are orchestrating others to do the above

As you go up this list, you can and should be doing more pure research to stay on top of advancements, and implementing challenging mathematical work into code.