# Can I ask for time to practice pen-testing on work hours

Tags: software-industry, communication, skills, learning

I work in a startup where we do IT Service. We build all kinds of apps (web, mobile, iot, etc.). I currently have a role of project leader (handling 3 projects) as well as the guy people come to for security.

Internally management sees me as the CISO. I have started creating documents for the teams on Security Best Practices and more on work hours as part of my "responsibilities" and my boss was ok with it.

Even though I do more coding and management than pen-testing I still love polishing my skills and learning more. I wanted to know if it made sense to ask to take 30 minutes a week to practice and do some pen-testing exercises like TryHackMe

Comment: There was a similar question, recently [Do employers allow workers to review materials relevant for the job during the working hours?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/163182/do-employers-allow-workers-to-review-materials-relevant-for-the-job-during-the-w)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, what's the problem? If the work area is known and considered part of your responsibilities, it'll actually look good if you ask to get trained to refresh / polish / sharpen your skills in that area.

One nitpick: you may want to use the term "learning" instead of "practice".

Go ahead.

Comment: Interesting downvote - any explanation please?

Comment: Why do you think "learning" would be better than "practice"?

Answer (score 4):

> Internally management sees me as the CISO

If you already have these responsibilities, then in my opinion you should change the way you approach your boss about this - instead of *"asking"* for time, **tell** your boss you **are going** to use time each week to improve your (and your team's, and therefore your boss's) capability in that area.

The specific way to do this is going to vary wildly depending on company cultures, office politics, and the individual personalities involved.

You'll need to judge for yourself how best to proceed, but **you've been given the responsibility already**, so do what you need to to carry it out.